# Persistent Byte Output Counter C++

Tags: c++, encryption, base64

I am working on a project in which I need to keep track of how many bytes the software dishes out. 
The software will be turned on and off occasionally, so I must implement a way to store the number of bytes outputted in a way so that an Administrator or another User cannot simply open the file and change the number of bytes outputted.
What is the best way to implement this? 
Also, I am not able to use any libraries (ex: boost).

Comment: please give us a better definition of "bytes the software dishes out". Do you want to log the stdout? or keep track of the allocations/deallocations?

Comment: _"... an Administrator or..."_ not possible by definition local administrators are god.  You would need to send the data to a remote computer over which you (or a trusted representative) have complete control.

Comment: There are dozens of ways to implement persistence: files, databases, local server, cloud server, etc. Pick one, write a program, and then we'll have something to help you with.

Comment: @RichardCritten ...only of the local machine. He could store the count on a cloud server to which only he has the password. Of course, hiding that password from someone who can look at his source might be tricky...

Comment: Would need to count how much data (in bytes) goes through a UDP channel. I need to store this number and have it sent remotely to a server at the end of every month. Implementing some sort of database seems overkill for this task.

Comment: How hard do you want to make it for someone to change/delete the count? Impossible is off the table.

Comment: Hard enough for the user not to be able to simply open a cleartext file and change the number "10000" to "0"...like resetting an odometer. I was thinking of tying this number to the encrypted license file, so if the user would want to tamper with it, they would corrupt it causing the software to stop working.

Comment: Target OS? In Windows you could throw it in the registry in some anonymous location and this would stop most people. A warning about trying to do this without third party libraries. If you want to do crypto and not use libraries, about the best anyone can do is point you at Schneier's Applied Cryptography and say "Start reading."

Comment: This looks simple enough https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Encryption_Algorithm Just tested and it works nicely. What you will probably need here is to encrypt your value with 2 different keys and have both results stored in file, then if modified the values will not match when decripting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Encryption_Algorithm

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

void encrypt(uint32_t* v, uint32_t* k) {
    uint32_t v0 = v[0], v1 = v[1], sum = 0, i;           /* set up */
    uint32_t delta = 0x9e3779b9;                     /* a key schedule constant */
    uint32_t k0 = k[0], k1 = k[1], k2 = k[2], k3 = k[3];   /* cache key */
    for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) {                       /* basic cycle start */
        sum += delta;
        v0 += ((v1 << 4) + k0) ^ (v1 + sum) ^ ((v1 >> 5) + k1);
        v1 += ((v0 << 4) + k2) ^ (v0 + sum) ^ ((v0 >> 5) + k3);
    }                                              /* end cycle */
    v[0] = v0; v[1] = v1;
}

void decrypt(uint32_t* v, uint32_t* k) {
    uint32_t v0 = v[0], v1 = v[1], sum = 0xC6EF3720, i;  /* set up */
    uint32_t delta = 0x9e3779b9;                     /* a key schedule constant */
    uint32_t k0 = k[0], k1 = k[1], k2 = k[2], k3 = k[3];   /* cache key */
    for (i = 0; i<32; i++) {                         /* basic cycle start */
        v1 -= ((v0 << 4) + k2) ^ (v0 + sum) ^ ((v0 >> 5) + k3);
        v0 -= ((v1 << 4) + k0) ^ (v1 + sum) ^ ((v1 >> 5) + k1);
        sum -= delta;
    }                                              /* end cycle */
    v[0] = v0; v[1] = v1;
}

int main()
{
    uint32_t k[4] = { 123,456,789,10 }; // key
    uint32_t v[2] = { 1000000, 1000000 }; // data


    // save into file
    std::ofstream ofs("save.dat", std::ios::binary);
    encrypt(v, k);
    ofs << v[0] << " " << v[1] << std::endl;



    // read from file
    std::ifstream ifs("save.dat", std::ios::binary);
    uint32_t v2[2];

    if (ifs >> v2[0] >> v2[1])
    {
        std::cout << "Filedata: " << v2[0] << " " << v2[1] << std::endl;

        decrypt(v2, k);

        if (v2[0] == v2[1])
            std::cout << "Decrypted: " << v2[0] << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << "Data was tampered with!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=d725bf798ff8ca12

Works pretty good and doesn't need any library. This is low level protection but should be hard enough to discourage your users.